# stdin, stdout, stderr работа с многопоточностью

Tags: многопоточность, процесс, multiprocessing

Как я понимаю при созданий нового процесса по умолчанию запускаются такие потоки как (strin, stdout, stderr) внутри этого процесса?

Comment: Во-первых, распишите, пожалуйста, конкретнее свой вопрос. Во-вторых, что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы путаете программные потоки и потоки ввода-вывода

Comment: Похоже, что вы путаете потоки ввода/вывода с потоками выполнения.

Comment: такая путаница у многих связана именно с переводом, в англоязычной версии это thread и stream, почему-то вышло как вышло, но и то и то часто переводят как поток.